# Nodejs sequelize RangeError using mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ubuntu, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize in nodejs along with mysql. I'm trying to run the command `npx sequelize db:create` but it giving me this error. Not sure what to do here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.4, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.6.2]

Loaded configuration file "src/config.js".

Using environment "development".
internal/buffer.js:83 
    throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(type || 'offset', RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range.

It must be >= 0 and <= 5. Received 9 at boundsError (internal/buffer.js:83:9) 
at Buffer.readUInt32LE (internal/buffer.js:217:5) 
at Packet.readInt32 (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:103:24) 
at Function.fromPacket (/root/sequelize-> > test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/handshake.js:63:32) 
at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:93:40) 
at ClientHandshake.execute (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:39:22) 
at Connection.handlePacket (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
at PacketParser.onPacket (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12) 
at PacketParser.executeStart (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16) at Socket. (/root/sequelize-test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25) 
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28) at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12) 
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9) 
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) 
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) { code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE' }
```

my config of database

```js
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root123456',
    database: 'test_run',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 33060,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    timezone: '+06:00',
    // dialectOptions: {
      //   bigNumberStrings: true,
      // },
    },
};
```

Comment: this looks like a bug in the `mysql2` module and how it interacts with the MySQL server. Please find/create a bug report starting your MySQL server version and the sql implemented that was sent along with your connection information.

Comment: when I change the port ot `3306` then it shows access denied error

Comment: answer is till the same. This got past the connection stage of the client mysql2 implementation and then internally failed. It was probably expecting a different server response.

Comment: UPDATE: I reinstall mysql and created a user then the command 'npx sequelize db:create` worked. But when I tried to run the app, the same error showed and the app crashed.

Comment: When you ignore advice, and restart/reinstall without any analysis, you don't learn very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have globally installed MySQL2 using this command:

```
npm i -g mysql2
```

If the problem persists, try downgrading node version to 10.

Regards